# Creating A Sound Loop

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I am using the following code to play a wav file. I want the have the file play over and over until the user clicks a button. How might I do this?

```
Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Audio/ape.wav");
        SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [SoundEffectInstance.IsLooped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940203.aspx) for this. and SoundEffectInstance.Stop on button click.

Comment: kindly check the link as it has the sample code for you perusal